# Independence in Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I've read two times in different lecture notes that for a Brownian Motion $(B_s)_{s\ge 0}$ and $t<u$ the random variable $B^t_{u}:=B_{t+u}-B_t$ is independent from ${\cal F}_t:=\sigma\{B_s:s\le t\}$. Now the definition of Brownian Motion tells us that $B^t_u$ is independent from the individual $B_s$ but how do I climb up to the whole $\sigma$-field?

If I'm not mistaken it would suffice to prove independence for a $\cap$-closed generator of the $\sigma$-field, using the $\lambda$-$\pi$-theorem and such.  But it's still puzzling me how to prove that $B^t_u$ is independent from events of the form $\{B_{s(i)}\in{A_i}:0\le i<n\}$ where $s(i)<t$ and $A_i\in{\cal B}({\bf R})$.

Comment: Actually, "the definition of Brownian motion tells us" much more than what you say. What is your source?

Comment: Lecture notes from the internet. I know that it tells us more, I'm currently trying to use the facts that $B_{s(i+1)}-B_{s(i)}$ are also independent from $B^t_u$, maybe I will succeed this way.

Comment: Think I got it. You start with even simpler events, namely $\{B_{s(i)}\in (a_i,\infty):0\le i<n\}$ for $s(i)\le t$, $a_i\in{\bf Q}$. These can be written as the union (assume $n=2$ for readability) $$\cup_{x\in{\bf Q}\cap (0,\infty)} \{B_{s(0)}\in(a_0+x,\infty),B_{s(1)}-B_{s(0)}\in(a_1-a_0-x,\infty)\}.$$ Since the events $\{B_{s(0)}\in A,B_{s(1)}-B_{s(0)}\in A'\}$ for $A,A'\in{\cal B}({\bf R})$ form a semi-ring, the union from above can be written as a disjoint union using only elements which are independent from $B^u_t$, hence the union itself is independent and we are done.